# how to create a widget layer in awesome wm with compton for screenlets

Tags: widget, awesome-wm

My google foo has produced no answers, and I'm not sure if this is something that would be implemented in compton, or awesome, or both need to be configured (compton is a fork of xcompmgr-dana)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.